Getting a device's precise position using the browser geolocation API
I want to build a progressive Web-App vario which makes use of the Browsers APis to serve as an instrument which essentially detects whether the user's altitude is increasing or decreasing and then outputs some type of sound to indicate this. This device is very common in paragliding and makes paragliding especially for beginners much easier and more comfortable.
I tried to track the user's altitude with the geolocation API, but using watchPosition to keep track of the user's position does not update the values frequently enough for me to track the users altitude precisely enough.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Höhenmessung</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="noahfunctions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Höhenmessung</h1>
    <p>Diese Seite verwendet die Geolokalisierungsfunktionen des Browsers, um die Höhe des Benutzers zu verfolgen.</p>
    <button id="startHeightWatch">Höhenüberwachung starten</button>
    <button id="stopHeightWatch">Höhenüberwachung stoppen</button>
    <div id="height"></div>
    <div id="latitude"></div>
    <div id="ascent_descent"></div>
</body>
</html>


$(document).ready(function() {

    // Todo: Make Threshold value. The change in height should only trigger if the change is greater than the threshold value.
    let watchID;
    let initialAltitude;
    let previousAltitude;
    let currentAltitude;
    
    // const ascentSound = new Audio("ascent.mp3");
    // const descentSound = new Audio("descent.mp3");

    $("#startHeightWatch").click(function() {
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                initialAltitude = position.coords.altitude;
                previousAltitude = initialAltitude;
                currentAltitude = initialAltitude;
            }, errorHandler, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
            watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(updateHeight, errorHandler, { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 0});
            console.log("Höhenüberwachung gestartet (ID: " + watchID + ")");
        } else {
            console.error("Geolocation wird von diesem Browser nicht unterstützt.");
        }
    });

    $("#stopHeightWatch").click(function() {
        if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
            console.log("Höhenüberwachung gestoppt");
        } else {
            console.error("Geolocation wird von diesem Browser nicht unterstützt.");
        }
    });

    function updateHeight(position) {
        const { latitude, longitude, altitude } = position.coords;
        currentAltitude = altitude;
        if (previousAltitude - currentAltitude >= 0) {
            $("#ascent_descent").html("Abstieg");
            // descentSound.play();
            // abstieg
        }
        else if (previousAltitude - currentAltitude < 0) {
            $("#ascent_descent").html("Aufstieg");
            // ascentSound.play();  
            // aufstieg
        }
        previousAltitude = currentAltitude;
        console.log("Höhe: " + altitude + " Meter");
        $("#height").html("Longitude: " + longitude + " | Höhe: " + altitude.toFixed(2) + " Meter<br>");
        $("#latitude").html("Latitude: " + latitude);
    }

    function errorHandler(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                console.error("Benutzer hat die Standortfreigabe abgelehnt.");
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                console.error("Höheninformationen sind nicht verfügbar.");
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                console.error("Die Höhenabfrage dauerte zu lange.");
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                console.error("Ein unbekannter Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
                break;
        }
    }
});


Trying to call the getCurrentPosition function a couple time per second also does not work as expected.
$(document).ready(function() {
    let initialAltitude;
    let previousAltitude;
    let currentAltitude;
    let counter = 0;    
    let flag = true;
    
    $("#startHeightWatch").click(function() {
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                initialAltitude = position.coords.altitude;
                previousAltitude = initialAltitude;
                currentAltitude = initialAltitude;
            }, errorHandler, { enableHighAccuracy: true });

            // Request altitude updates at a high frequency (approximately 10 times per second)
            let updateInterval = setInterval(requestAltitudeUpdate, 200);

            console.log("Höhenüberwachung gestartet (Intervall: " + updateInterval + ")");
        } else {
            console.error("Geolocation wird von diesem Browser nicht unterstützt.");
        }
    });

    $("#stopHeightWatch").click(function() {
        flag = false;
        clearInterval(updateInterval);
        console.log("Höhenüberwachung gestoppt");
    });

    async function requestAltitudeUpdate() {
        if (flag){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateHeight, errorHandler, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
        }
    }

    async function updateHeight(position) {
        counter++;
        const { latitude, longitude, altitude } = position.coords;
        currentAltitude = altitude;
        if (previousAltitude - currentAltitude >= 0) {
            $("#ascent_descent").html("Abstieg");
        } else if (previousAltitude - currentAltitude < 0) {
            $("#ascent_descent").html("Aufstieg");
        }
        previousAltitude = currentAltitude;
        console.log("Höhe: " + altitude + " Meter");
        $("#height").html("Longitude: " + longitude + " | Höhe: " + altitude + " Meter<br>");
        $("#latitude").html("Latitude: " + latitude + " | Counter: " + counter + "<br>");
    }

    function errorHandler(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                console.error("Benutzer hat die Standortfreigabe abgelehnt.");
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                console.error("Höheninformationen sind nicht verfügbar.");
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                console.error("Die Höhenabfrage dauerte zu lange.");
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                console.error("Ein unbekannter Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
                break;
        }
    }
});


If anyone has any suggestions on how I would be able to keep track of the users altitude and position frequently enough to determine if a paraglider is moving up or down.
Thanks in advance! Any help would be highly appreciated.
